# Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document when using .Save()

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm writing an XML file using C# and Linq but when trying to save it gives me the 'Token EndDocument in state Document would result in an invalid XML document' error. The code for the creation and saving of the document:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
using (var db = new CarRentalEntities1())
{
    foreach (Car c in db.Cars)
    {
        XElement root = new XElement("root",
        new XElement
            (
                "Car-" + c.CarName,
                new XAttribute("CarID", c.CarID),
                new XAttribute("CarName", c.CarName),
                new XAttribute("CarType", c.CarType),
                new XAttribute("Reg", c.Registration),
                new XAttribute("YearOfPurchase", c.YearOfPurchase)
            )
        );
    }
    xDoc.Save("D:\\Cars.XML");
}
```

Comment: You're not adding anything to `xDoc`, so you're saving an empty `XDocument` to the file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply that fixed it after a few tries and messing around. Sorry if this was a dumb question this is my first time using XML so I'm not completely sure about how everything works. P.S Is there any way to use xattributes in a foreach loop?

Answer (score 8):

You're not adding anything to `xDoc`, so you're saving an empty `XDocument` to the file.

From @MarcinJuraszek comment above.